# PHP uploader and htaccess password problems

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've got a rather baffling question/problem, let me lay it out for you.

I have two directories -- gallery and uploader

The uploader directory is htaccess password protected. This is where several PHP pages and the PHP file uploader reside. I enter my credentials when I access the index PHP file when I load a the index within the directory.

The problem is that the uploader is uploading the files and then moving it to the gallery directory (not password protected). It then runs other scripts to copy that image, resize it, then delete the original. This process works beautifully until I put the htaccess password on the uploader directory.  So for some reason the PHP uploader in a protected directory can't move/work on the uploaded image and then copy it to the un-protected directory.

Any ideas of what I need to do? I'm not sure if the issue is the PHP uploader calling other scripts in the protected directory or if it's having troubles when moving it to the un-protected directory.

EDIT:
Here is some sample code and as you can see URLs aren't being used (nor are they in the resizeMyImageTN method).

```
//WHERE THE SAVE HAPPENS!


move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], '../../uploads/'.$folder.'/'.$new_index.'-' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name']);


//Call function to resize images pass in path

resizeMyImageTN($_FILES['Filedata']['name'],$folder, $new_index);


unlink('../../uploads/'.$folder.'/'.$new_index.'-' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to answer this (my bad).  In the end I could only get it to work by not having the upload directory .htaccess protected.  Which wasn't ideal but I couldn't seem to figure anything else out.   Since I asked this I have converted the site to Django and that has fixed all my problems.

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess protection works at the webserver level. But, UNLESS you're using URLs in your various file-manipulation calls, the PHP script works at the filesystem level and would never see the .htaccess protection.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], '/some/dir/that/is/protected/newname.txt');
```

would not involve the HTTP layer, which means no protection. But if you were try

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], 'http://myserver.com/newname.txt');
```

that would involve a new HTTP request, re-upload the file, and be subject to any URl restrictions in place on the server.

Without seeing some code, we most likely can't answer your question.

Comment: If the uploader script is calling other scripts, as you say, I'd check if any of those are being invoked via http (there'd be evidence of this in the site's access_log).

Comment: The only other one being called is another PHP file that I include using the standard PHP include statement.  (It's in a sub-folder within the same protected directory).  It's a PHP image resizer and uses a relative path as a parameter to save the picture (i.e. ../../gallery/upload)